# My program Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: null

Tags: java

I am getting "exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: null".

My code:

```
package luastanah;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Luastanah {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String stipe = null;
    // TODO code aString stipe=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("masukkan tipe"); //Digunakan untuk menampilkan sebuah pop up yang berisi perintah untuk memasukkan sebuah nilai.
    int tipe=Integer.parseInt(stipe);// Digunakan untuk merubah inputan menjadi bertipe data Integer.
   String stanah=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("masukkan luas tanah"); //Digunakan untuk menampilkan sebuah pop up yang berisi perintah untuk memasukkan sebuah nilai.
    int tanah=Integer.parseInt(stanah);// Digunakan untuk merubah inputan menjadi bertipe data Integer.
    String srumah=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("masukkan luas rumah"); //Digunakan untuk menampilkan sebuah pop up yang berisi perintah untuk memasukkan sebuah nilai.
    int rumah=Integer.parseInt(srumah);// Digunakan untuk merubah inputan menjadi bertipe data Integer.

    switch (tipe){
        case 1:{//digunakan untuk pengambilan keputusan pernyataan telah disediakan.            case 1:{
            int harga=tanah*50000+rumah*2000000;//digunakan untuk menghitung data harga yang berniali integer.
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"total="+harga);//Digunakan untuk menampilkan sebuah pop up keterangan dari hasil yang telah dieksekusi.
            break;//digunakan untuk menghentikan proses yang terjadi apabila perintah untuk eksekusi telah dilaksanakan.
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have to initialize your variable.

```
String stipe = "1";
```

You cannot keep it null as you using it generate the value for the variable tipe.

```
int tipe = Integer.parseInt(stipe);
```

As the document states,  **it throws NumberFormatException if the string does not contain a parsable integer.**

Referenses : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)